# onSelect is not working on Datepicker Widget

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Javascript doesn't seem to enter onSelect, when I select something. I already set an alert there which doesn't show (other onChange functions in my script are working)

When the User clicks on a date, a Dropdown Menu with dynamic options should show.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#cal").datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  });
});

var status = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cal").datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      var datum = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
      alert("Datum erfolgreich ausgelesen: " + datum);

      if (datum) {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'ajax.php',
          data: 'datum=' + datum,
          success: function(html) {
            $('#uhrzeit').html(html);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<label for="cal">Wunschtermin Buchen
  <div id="cal" name="cal"></div>
</label>
```

Comment: Does that even work to begin with, initializing the datepicker on a div element? Usually that is done on a text input field …

Comment: @04FS yep, it shows the datepicker inline, instead of toggling it on focus of the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you already defined the datepicker on the `#cal` element in your first document.ready handler, so the attempt to initialise it again with different settings in the second document.ready is ignored.

To fix this, join both document.ready handler in to one and instantiate the `#cal` datepicker one time with *all* the settings you require, like this:

```js
var status = 0;

$(function() {
  $("#cal").datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      var datum = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
      console.log("Datum erfolgreich ausgelesen: " + datum);

      if (datum) {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'ajax.php',
          data: { datum: datum },
          success: function(html) {
            $('#uhrzeit').html(html);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<label for="cal">Wunschtermin Buchen
  <div id="cal" name="cal"></div>
</label>
```

Also note the use of an object in `data` here to let jQuery serialise the querystring for you, and also the use of `console.log()` instead of `alert()` for debugging. The latter should be avoided as it coerces data types and also blocks the UI thread, which is annoying.

Comment: thank you very much! yeah it makes sense, now that I think about it. Man I feel a little stupid now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Declare it just once, that's how it's working:

```
 <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var status = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#cal" ).datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst){
            var datum = $(this).datepicker( "getDate" );
            alert("Datum erfolgreich ausgelesen: "+datum);

            if(datum){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'GET',
                    url:'ajax.php',
                    data: 'datum='+datum,
                    success:function(html){
                        $('#uhrzeit').html(html);
                    }           
                });
            }
        }
    });
});

</script>
<label for = "cal">Wunschtermin Buchen
   <div id="cal" name="cal"></div>
</label>
```